# Uploading files Formdata and JSON data in the same request with Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http-headers, form-data

How to combine my two $http.post into single http post?

```
$scope.myMethod = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    angular.forEach($scope.files, function(file){
        fd.append('file', file);
    });

    $http.post('my_url', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).success(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });

    $http.post('my_url', {imgx: $scope.imgx, imgy: $scope.imgy, imgh: $scope.imgh, imgw: $scope.imgw}).success(
        function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

any help is very appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
try something like this:

$scope.myMethod = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    angular.forEach($scope.files, function(file){
        fd.append('file', file);
    });

var data = {};
    data.fd = fd;
    data.otherData  =   {imgx: $scope.imgx, imgy: $scope.imgy, imgh: $scope.imgh, imgw: $scope.imgw};  

    $http.post('my_url', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).success(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });


}
```

Comment: Thank you @SharpCoder, Can you explain your suggested answer? for me to know how it works. Thanks

Comment: @user1157768: Earlier you were sending only `fd` object. Now I have created another object called `data`. this `data` object had two proeprties `fd & otherData`. For this to work you have to change server side code as well. instead of expecting only fd or other object you will get another typeof object which will have both fd and other object which you were sending.

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/

(Just came across this when looking for info on doing this from a .Net client.)

Answer (score 0):

without combine them you can listen to the 2 promises like this:

```
var promise1 = $http.post('my_url', fd, { .....

var promise2 = $http.post('my_url', {imgx: $scope.imgx, ......

$q.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(response){ console.log(response); });
```

angular $q [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did and worked for me.

In frontend:

```
return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: function (data) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("name", data.name);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("content", data.files[i]);
            }
            return formData;
        },
        data: { name: name, files: files }
    });
```

In server side, just the normal way retrieving the parameters depending on the language you use, I'm using `NodeJS`, this is how it looks like:

```
var name = req.body.name;
req.file('content').upload(...);
```

I referenced [this](https://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/). It took me lots of time getting this work because of my mistake. Hope this would help anyone who needs this and for a record as well.